# Designing Widgets for Android

Tags: android, widget

I'm currently working on programming widgets in Android, however I'd like a second opinion on how I should go about designing them, particularly in regards to graphic sizes.

I have already read the App Widget Design Guidelines in the official documentation, where 1 cell on the home screen is said to be roughly 40dp. Given 8dp as margins, this means I'll be sizing my widget at 32dpx32dp for 1 cell. Using the calculator found [here](http://labs.skinkers.com/content/android_dp_px_calculator/), this equates to 24(ldpi), 32(mdpi), 48(hdpi) and 64(xhdpi) pixels for my widget graphic sizes. I will of course be using 9patch graphics. An icon within the widget will be appropriately sized for a given screen density, then stored in drawable-mdpi or whichever is appropriate for the given graphic.

Is the discussed technique appropriate, or have I somehow overseen some major flaw? One thing that does concern me is that 64px on a xhdpi screen seems rather small, seeing that launcher icons are (i think) 96px for xhdpi. Nevertheless, I would greatly appreciate any advice on the matter and whether or not I should be going about this a different way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some simple widget demo.So you will get better idea.This link will be helpful to you. http://buildmobile.com/how-to-code-an-android-widget/

http://www.androidwidget.info/create-android-widget/

Comment: Thanks but these don't give a great deal of insight into the graphical aspect. They mainly focus on the code.